# Can I set a php.ini (upload_max_filesize) variable in .htaccess to only apply to one .php file?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, php

I'm not sure if this is possible, but here's what I would like to do.

I have a .php script that uploads and then manipulates the file.  I only want that particular .php script to be allowed to upload large files, the php.ini settings should apply for all others.

Can I edit the .htaccess file to affect only the one .php script?

In pseudo-code:

`if (myPhpScript.php) {

   php_value  upload_max_filesize  16M 

}`

Thanks!

Comment: http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/01/uploading-larger-files-in-php.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to use the [`Files`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/core.html#files) directive in .htaccess:

```
<Files myPhpScript.php>
    php_value upload_max_filesize 16M 
</Files>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but you could just use the function ini_set() within the php file you want to have the ini value changed. See: http://php.net/ini_set

Comment: Nope, afraid not, for this setting it has to be done in the .htaccess file or the php.ini file